# Getting Swagger UI oauth2 work with oidc-provider

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, swagger-ui, openapi, oidc-provider

I am trying to get Swagger UI to successfully authorize to a [oidc-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oidc-provider) instance.

I have set up a minimal (as possible) instance on glitch here: https://glitch.com/~copper-vise

What it does is:

- have swagger UI on /doc serving the definition from the swagger.yaml file
- run the oidc provider with minimal configuration and dev interactions.

The problem is that I don't seem to be able to get the two work together. It seems like it could be a Swagger UI bug, but considering my lack of experience with oidc it might simply be a configuration issue.

To try, click the "Authorize" button on the [swagger interface](https://copper-vise.glitch.me/doc/), use `foo` and `bar` for the `client_id` and `client_secret`, check at least the openid scope and click "Authorize". At this point you should get a login prompt. Enter anything you like and login. At this point the swagger UI should be having a token, but I never got it that far.

What I'm getting instead is a `invalid_client` error, it seems like the oidc-provider expects an authorization request header that the Swagger UI is not providing. The "implicit" flow does not seem to work at all either. As far as [I can tell](https://copper-vise.glitch.me/.well-known/openid-configuration), these are the two flows that the oidc-provider supports (with this configuration?).

I'm stuck, not sure where to go from here. It seems like the right combination of the openapi securitySchemes configuration in the `swagger.yaml` file and the oidc-provider and client options should get this running.

Answer (score 0):

It seems swagger is sending `client_secret_post` client authentication, the default on the IdP is `client_secret_basic`. If you change the client configuration on the IdP to match the scheme the client is actually using it'll work.